# Is there any alternative firmware for ZTE zxv10 w300

Tags: router, bandwidth, firmware

I am sharing a ADSL connection with  my friends using a  ZTE w300 wireless router. However as many people are sharing the connection when one person is downloading  the bandwidth cannot be throtelled. I have come across firmware such as
[Gargoyle router](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/),  [Openwrt](https://openwrt.org/) however the website doesnt say that it supports the above router. can anyone suggest  a software or a firmware which has the ability or  monitoring and throtling the bandwidth per user/ip

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that what you are looking for does not exist - Openwrt. Gargoyle Router, Tomato, DD-WRT etc are all "Linux based", and have extremely limited support (if any) for ADSL connections.  If [this post](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=716168) is anything to go by your router is definitely not supported.